# How to manipulate the limit for 'e' in order to get the following limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I understand that $$e=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$ but how exactly do I manipulate this expression in order to get the expressions below?

Compute the following limits:

(i) $\quad \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(1+ \frac{1}{3x})^{2x}$

(ii) $\quad \lim\limits_{x \to 0+}(1+ \frac{1}{3x})^{2x}$

Hint: Use the fact that $a^x = e^{x\ln a}.$

The answer for (i) is $e^{2/3}$ and for (ii) is $1.$ But I dont know how to get to them. I tried re-arranging the expression using the given hint and simplifying a little bit but cant find a way to move on. Thank you so much.

Comment: $$\left(1+\frac1{3x}\right)^{\!2x}=\left[\left(1+\frac1{3x}\right)^{3x}\right]^{\!\frac23}.$$

Comment: Do you know $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (1+ \frac{1}{x})^x =1$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews its not stated in the question at all

Comment: The second one only looks like your first limit, but the $x\to0+$ makes it different.

Comment: @Henry Sorry, misread your comment.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes perfect sense :)

Comment: @Tom Wiesley I reverted your last edit. Even if the question was answered, never delete the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion given in the comments are fine, to proceed according to the given hint we have

$$\left(1+ \frac{1}{3x}\right)^{2x}=e^{2x \log \left(1+ \frac{1}{3x}\right)}$$

and then for the first one as $x \to \infty$ we can consider

$$2x \log \left(1+ \frac{1}{3x}\right)=\frac23\frac{\log \left(1+ \frac{1}{3x}\right)}{\frac1{3x}}$$

and for the second one as $x \to 0^+$ we can consider

$$2x \log \left(1+ \frac{1}{3x}\right)=\left(\frac23+2x\right)\frac{\log \left(1+ \frac{1}{3x}\right)}{1+ \frac{1}{3x}}$$

To conclude we need to use the following standard limit

- for the first one $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$
- for the second one $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\log x}x=0$

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful solution.

Comment: @TomWiesley You are welcome! Are you aware about the standard limits here indicated?

Comment: Yes I am aware of the standard limits you included here. It is actually the exact ones that were used in my lectures, I just didnt see how I can use it here. So it is actually perfect. I get all your working but I dont really see how I can get the limit equal to 1 for the second one. Since $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}( \frac{logx}{x})= 0 $, doesnt this make the entire limit be equal to 0 for the second case? This cant be true because the answer should be 1 according to my solution manual.. Thank you again.. I am probably not seeing something here

Comment: @TomWiesley For the second one we have $u=1+\frac1{3x}\to \infty$ and then the relevant limit is $\lim_{u\to \infty} \frac{\log u}u=0$ from which we obtain $e^0=1$.

Comment: Ahhh! Ofcouurse! I will never forget this help :)

Comment: @TomWiesley Well done! I suggest to work a lot with standard limits, solving many exercise and studying their proof. Bye

Comment: I have one last thing to ask... Everything is clear except I cant see how you went from $$2x \log \left(1+ \frac{1}{3x}\right)$$ to this $$\left(\frac23+2x\right)\frac{\log \left(1+ \frac{1}{3x}\right)}{1+ \frac{1}{3x}}$$ ? What were the steps in between? Thank you again :)

Comment: We multiply denominator and numerator by $(1+1/3x)$ in such way to have the right expression for the standard limit which refer to.

Comment: Got it! :) I understand it completely now